# CSS image with concave shape cut out?

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

[image]

Is it possible to create the bottom curve on this image using only CSS?

I've seen and tried many of the countless fiddles showing how to use `border-radius` but the problem is that the corners never result in a sharp edge.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: using border-radius can achieve the very similar thing you want. I think looks like only `svg` can help in solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Right, but `border-radius` leaves slightly rounded corners; these corners need to be sharp :-\

Comment: @cfx Please show us the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution without using svg is very tricky, the idea is you need some wrapper containing your actual image, this wrapper should have a very large size (in this example, I used the size `945 x 500`) so that it can render a large curve. We need to set the `overflow:hidden` for this container to hide other overflow part of the inner image. This trick will function like a ***clipper*** which can cut off the image by the curve.

Also note that we will use some fairly new feature of CSS3 in this example (without them I don't think we can do at best), that is the `clip` property, in fact we don't really need this (because the background of the container is transparent which will be seen through). For `clip` to work, we have to apply `position:absolute` for the container, that means we have to use absolute position for the container. So to position the container, you have to change the `left` and `top` property. In fact there are offsets between the actual image and the container, so there will be a problem, for example, the horizontal offset is `200px`, but when you set the `left` position for the container as `100px`, you want that is exactly the `left` of the inner image. If we don't do anything, normally the `left` of the inner image will be `100 + 200 = 300px`. So to deal with this, we have to apply some `translate` transform to the container (translate it horizontally about `-200px`, so the final computed value for the left will be `300px - 200px = 100px` which is the result we want. Here are the code details:

**HTML**:

```
<div id='clipper'>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#clipper > div {    
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(http://placekitten.com/400/200);                
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(50% - 300px);
  top: calc(100% - 200px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
}
#clipper {     
  border-bottom-left-radius:1800px 500px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:1800px 800px;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:500px;
  width: 945px;    
  position:absolute;
  clip: rect(300px, 573px, 500px,173px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-173px, -300px);    
  left: 100px;
  top:50px;    
}
```

### [Working Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/q9344/2)

**NOTE**: The blur effect I used in the example is just for demonstrative purpose, it works only on webkit-based browsers, I know it's hard to have a cross-browser solution and I suppose it's your own part. The last thing I want to note is I've already mentioned that this is very tricky, it requires ***trial and error***, if you want to change the size of the image, you may have to redo the steps with ***trial and error*** to achieve the effect you want. This answer just mainly shows the principle and mechanism to achieve the effect.

**Issue**: Looks like there is still a nasty issue, although the large container `clipper` is clipped and transparent but it is still able to make the horizontal scrollbar appear. I think this issue is fairly annoying. We can set the `body { overflow-x:hidden;}` but it depends on other contents... I hope someone will find a nice solution for this issue and post directly or as link reference in the comment. I would be appreciated that.

**Update**: Just found the solution for the issue above, we need to wrap another container with the size being equal to the inner image, set `overflow:hidden` for this outermost container. Of course to position the inner image, we just change the `left` and `top` of this outermost container (instead of the `clipper` as before). Here is the [Complete Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/q9344/3/)

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. The demo looks very promising although probably very tricky to make this responsive.

Comment: @cfx yes, I'm not sure about responsive design with this one but it may be a good start for you. BTW, `SVG` is always the best choice once all the old browsers are not used by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

border-radius starts from the center of District
if u set border-radius value equal or more that width or height you can create a rounded shape but i dont think thats what you want.

check this

```
border-radius: 0 0 400px 400px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALytT/

but you might create a realy large rounded shape above your image and set the

```
overflow:hidden;
z-index:111;/* more than your image */
```

to create this effect