# Crop triangle from image in CSS

Tags: css, image, position, crop

Our designer wants to do that:

[image: crop]

But I can't figure out a good way to do this triangle crop:

- With an `:after` that takes all the width and uses some kind of borders trick to make a triangle
- With a big `:after` element that is rotated and white, but it should not hide any other text
- With some magic filter I don't know?
- By using a canvas, cropping it in JS, then loading the image as a base64 url? (Maybe overkill :D)

What do you think?

Comment: :after with border trick (or gradient) should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: version 2: http://jsfiddle.net/mtaU8/4/ works with changing bg.

Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/mtaU8/

HTML: (I used a `div` with a background, but you could easily use an `img` element.)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

CSS: (mostly fluff for setup, but basically use `transform:rotate()` on an `:after` content, then position it so it slices your picture nicely. Contain all that in your container and you're good to go.)

```
.container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}
.img:after{
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height:125px;
    background-color: white;
    top:90px;
    left:-20px;
   transform: rotate(5deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);

}
```

Comment: Yes, and here you are http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/mtaU8/1/ The solid red background color of the body is just an example, when we have an image background or a gradient background, this solution can't make it better than showing the ugly solid (white) color part to the user.

Comment: Yes, the `:after` element must match the background content, so it won't work if you have a changing background. From the mockup, looks like Dorian has a white BG though. Did you have a better, solution, King King? I'm sure Dorian would appreciate it.

Comment: looks like you have never heard about ***overflow clipping technique***. With this technique you can clip off the thing to render even a star (which shows OK on image background).

Comment: You can learn about that technique via this demo (I've made it myself) which renders a Hexagon http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/DL5Hc/ It's so fantastic.

Comment: Updated to allow changing BG. Also, why don't you post your answer as an actual answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: because it's a little easy and I don't want to repeat doing something too much. You can find another similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178340/css-image-with-concave-shape-cut-out/23179075#23179075 which I answered. It's more complicated than the clipping in this question.

Comment: So you knew a simple and easy answer, but you were going to just criticize a sub-par answer without providing a better answer or even providing a link to more useful info? I don't get that. Why not just share your "easy" answer from the outset, instead of forcing other users to draw it out of you?

Comment: What if my width has to be 100%?

Comment: @JeremyKnees have you tried converting all `px` to `%` (with adjustments to the value, obviously)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the CSS clip property:

```
.crop {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(110px, 160px, 170px, 60px);
}
```

The clip property's `rect` value represents the section of the image that will be cropped. Here's a [demo](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/01/16/understanding-the-css-clip-property/).